# Linear algebra question about determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Is this equation true? A is any size real square matrix.
$$
\det  \left (\sum_{i=1}^{n} {A_{i}}^{t}A_{i} \right )\geq 0
$$

Comment: Please don't use pictures, use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Tell us what you think

Comment: I guess yes but cant prove

Comment: What are the $A_i$ supposed to mean?

Comment: Is t an random number or did you mean $A^T$ ?

Comment: Are the $A_i$s the columns of $A$ ?

Comment: T is for transpose and $A_{i}$s are matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the matrices are real, then all the $A_i^\top A_i$-s are [positive semidefinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix). Since the set of positive semidefinite matrices is a closed [convex cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone) in $\Bbb R^{k\times k}$, the sum is positive semidefinite itself and its determinant is $\ge0$. Moreover, you have the identity $$\ker\left(\sum_{j=1}^n A_j^\top A_j\right)=\bigcap_{j=1}^n \ker(A_j)$$ which implies that the inequality is strict if and only if $\bigcap_{j=1}^n\ker (A_j)=\{0\}$.

The same holds if you substitute the finite sum of matrices with a convergent series.

Comment: [+1] Do you have references for the identity $\ker\left(\sum_{j=1}^n A_j^\top A_j\right)=\bigcap_{j=1}^n \ker(A_j)$ I didn't know ?

Comment: @JeanMarie It's really just a silly trick. You know that the sum $S$ is positive semidefinite, so for $\ker S$ you want the vectors such that $x^\top Sx=0$. But that can only be the case if $x^\top A_i^\top A_ix=0$ for all $i$, i.e. if and only if $A_ix=0$ for all $i$.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks.